# DCA : Labelling points with autoplot or ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, multivariate-testing, autoplot

I find very difficult to put labels for sites with a DCA in a autoplot or ggplot.
I also want to differentiate the points on the autoplot/ggplot according to their groups.
This is the data and the code I used and it went well until the command for autoplot/ggplot:

```
library(vegan)
data(dune)
d <- vegdist(dune)
csin <- hclust(d, method = "single")
cl <- cutree(csin, 3)
dune.dca <- decorana(dune)
autoplot(dune.dca)
```

This is the autoplot obtained:

[image: dca_autoplot]

I am using simple coding and I tried these codes but they didn't led me anywhere:

```
autoplot(dune.dca, label.size = 3, data = dune, colour = cl)
ggplot(dune.dca(x=DCA1, y=DCA2,colour=cl))
ggplot(dune.dca, display = ‘site’, pch = 16, col = cl)
ggrepel::geom_text_repel(aes(dune.dca))
```

If anyone has a simple suggestion, it could be great.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Make sure your example is reproducible by adding packages to your code. `Dune` is not part of base R. you should consider looking at the help file for `ggplot::geom_label` and the examples there in using `?ggplot::geom_label`. You should definitely also read a [guide](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/be-awesome-in-ggplot2-a-practical-guide-to-be-highly-effective-r-software-and-data-visualization) about ggplot2, to get familiar with the syntax. Right now that is where your isisue lies.

Comment: Hi.Thanks for the advice. Yes i read this guide already and there is nothing there about putting labels on a DCA. I spent two days trying to put labels and it didn't work. I use R for years and never posted anything. I think 100 times before asking for help, but this time nothing works. I don't understand why it is so complicated to add labels for an DCA ordination. I managed easily with PCA but it works differently with DCA apparently due to the structure of the results.

Comment: From your post it just seems like you are missing `autoplot(...) + geom_label(nudge.y = 0.25)` or something similar, replacing `...` with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the added information (package) I was able to go and dig a bit deeper.

The problem is (in short) that `autoplot.decorana` adds the data to the specific layer (either `geom_point` or `geom_text`). This is not inherited to other layers, so adding additional layers results in blank pages.

Basically notice that one of the 2 code strings below results in an error, and note the position of the `data` argument:

```
# Error: 
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data = mtcars, mapping = aes_string(x = 'hp', y = 'mpg')) +
  geom_label(aes(x = hp, y = mpg, label = cyl))
# Work:
ggplot(data = mtcars) + 
  geom_point(mapping = aes_string(x = 'hp', y = 'mpg')) +
  geom_label(aes(x = hp, y = mpg, label = cyl))
```

`ggvegan:::autoplot.decorana` places data as in the example the returns an error.

I see 2 ways to get around this problem:

1. Extract the layers data using `ggplot_build` or `layer_data` and create an overall or single layer mapping.
2. Extract the code for generating the data, and create our plot manually (not using `autoplot`).

I honestly think the second is simpler, as we might have to extract more information to make our data sensible. By looking at the source code of `ggvegan:::autoplot.decorana` (simply printing it to console by leaving out brackets) we can extract the below code which generates the same data as used in the plot

```
ggvegan_data <- function(object, axes = c(1, 2), layers = c("species", "sites"), ...){
  obj <- fortify(object, axes = axes, ...)
  obj <- obj[obj$Score %in% layers, , drop = FALSE]
  want <- obj$Score %in% c("species", "sites")
  obj[want, , drop = FALSE]
}
```

With this we can then generate any plot that we desire, with appropriate mappings rather than layer-individual mappings

```
dune.plot.data <- ggvegan_data(dune.dca)
p <- ggplot(data = dune.dca, aes(x = DCA1, DCA2, colour = Score)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_text(aes(label = Label), nudge_y = 0.3)
p
```

Which gives us what I hope is your desired output
[image: point+label plot (from code above)]

Comment: Thank you. This is great. Yes, this is what i was trying to obtain. I just wanted to display the sites without the species. I will try what you proposed. It wish ggplot was easier to use. Many thanks.

Comment: It is designed to be easy. But there are some things that can be unintuitive. This is definitely one of the cases, and I am guessing that the author doesn't know that this is the case. :-)

Comment: Looking at the [package repo](https://github.com/gavinsimpson/ggvegan/issues/10#issue-277457669) this is an issue the author is aware of. And looking at the source, the main reason for this choice, seems to be, that several plots has additional layers (such as arrows for `cca`).  One could try to open an issue and see if they wouldn't add the data to the primary layer.